# How to declare enums as extern with default values

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I want to create an enum in C++11 in such a way that I can declare some constants value in a source code while declaring them in header file:

A.hpp

```cpp
typedef enum class ABC: uint8_t
{
    CAR,
    DOG,
    HOUSE
};
extern ABC ABCType;
```

A.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.hpp"

ABCType = { CAR = 1, DOG = 2, HOUSE = 3 };
```

The reason to want this is the enum's initial values depend on some other library declarations and needs to be non-modifiable by users (just a coding style requirement for me). So, the user can use something like below:

```cpp
#include "A.hpp"

int classA::method()
{
    ...
    check(ABCType.HOUSE);
    ...
}
```

I tried this, but the VC++ IDE says "too many initializer values", why is that?

Comment: enums can't be partially defined.

Comment: How can I achieve the objective?

Comment: @Programmer By using something other than enums. Enumerator constants aren't external objects with linkage.

Comment: What are you trying to acchieve? I have the feeling you are trying to port a concept from one language to another

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps not exactly what you want, but could be useful.

*scoped_opaque_enum.hpp*

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

enum class ABC : uint8_t;

extern ABC CAR, DOG, HOUSE;
```

*scoped_opaque_enum.cpp*

```
#include "scoped_opaque_enum.hpp"

ABC CAR = static_cast<ABC>(1), DOG = static_cast<ABC>(2), HOUSE = static_cast<ABC>(3);
```

*use_soe.cpp*

```
#include "scoped_opaque_enum.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(CAR) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the list of extern will go long if I need to many defined enums - for my need there are around 20-30 enums values then need to define

Comment: @Programmer Yes, but that wouldn't be any different from your original idea, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Enum isn't a list of constants with various values (defined later).
Enum defines values for items at declaration only. For your example, 'CAR' will have value '0' (and 'HOUSE' is 2), etc.

For you requeirements, you can create a class with some constants or functions which return need values. You make child classes with additional values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your own requirement ain't a problem, this is the only way in C++. Once you define an enum class, the values into is are considered constants.

If you consider:

```
enum class Ext { SOME_VALUE};
```

And you want numeric values following it, I suggest writing:

```
enum class E : std:: underlying_t<Ext > { 
    CAT = static_cast<std:: underlying_t<Ext >>(Ext::SOME_VALUE)+1,
    DOG
  };
```

This way, CAT is defined as one higher than SOME_VALUE and DOG as one higher than CAT (always prev+1).